# Do Nuxt.js store functions only execute on client side. Or should I explicitly use proccess variable to make sure its run on the client side

Tags: vuex, nuxt.js

Is it necessary that the store functions will be executed only client side or is there any case where the store functions can be invoked by Nuxt server too?

Answer (score 2):

Store functions can absolutely be executed server side.  For example, [serverInit](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/646).  They can also *potentially* be called in lifecycle hooks that happen serverside, like `created` and `beforeCreate`.

However, it's exceedingly rare that you should be worried about this.  Generally, store actions or mutations are committed once on page load, and from then on as a result of user interaction which always happens client side.

So rather than using `process.server` checks everywhere, simply code your data fetching in your `mounted` hooks.

Comment: There are times when a store function is to be called on an event (like a button click). So I don't think that calling store functions in only hooks will be possible.

But thanks for the information of serverInit. Helps a lot :)

Comment: In those cases, they will never be called server side because there are no user interactions server side.  You should be placing any automatic store calls, like pre-fetching data, in client-only hooks if you want to ensure those are only run client side.